# Grub error after removing partition

Tags: boot, grub2, partitioning

So I think I've possibly done something pretty dumb. Basically I was running out of space on my ubuntu partition and I knew i had a 40GB partition at the end of the disk which was called OS2.

I'm 99% sure this was one I created years ago when I first had the idea of dualbooting my computer (long before I actually got around to doing it) and I double checked on the drive, there was nothing on it.

So I installed GParted live USB, ran it, formatted the NTFS OS2 partition into ext2 format and rebooted computer.

Now I get the following error from grub:

```
error: file '/boot/grub/i386-pc/normal.mod' not found.
grub rescue>
```

Obviously the "grub rescue" bit is a command prompt, but other than that, there's nothing I can do with the computer.

What can I do to get my computer back?

Many thanks!

Luke

Comment: Have you tried to repair grub as per this? http://askubuntu.com/questions/88384/how-can-i-repair-grub-how-to-get-ubuntu-back-after-installing-windows

Answer (score 0):

Whenever my GRUB breaks, I do the following to reinstall GRUB:

Prepare a bootable USB Stick (e.g. with [unetbootin](http://unetbootin.sourceforge.net/)) with the current Ubuntu image or burn a DVD. Now boot from it into a live system and open a terminal. Then type

```
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
sudo grub-update
```

**This assumes /dev/sda is your primary hard drive** and you want to install GRUB there ;). Afterwards you should have a working GRUB again.

**Note:** Sometimes GRUB fails to detect other operating systems. Mount the relevant partitions with Nautilus by simply clicking on them, if they don't show up in terminal, while executing grub-update.